# Как обращаться к столбцам коллекций скалярных типов внутри table()?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, коллекции

Предположим, у нас есть результат преобразования в таблицу.

Как обращаться к столбцам в такой таблице?

```
declare
  a t_numbers;
  c t_numbers;
begin
  
  select * bulk collect into a from (select 1 d from dual union all select 2 d from dual);
  select * bulk collect into c from table(a) a1 where a1.??? = 2;
                                                   ------^^^
  FOR i IN 1..c.COUNT LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c(i));
  END LOOP;
end;
```

Comment: Точно также как и к столбцам обычной таблицы. В чем конкрето проблема?

Comment: @0xdb Вы бы лучше написали конкретный ответ =) Вместо вопросов что нужно написать? Ведь столбцы по сути не имеют имён в данном случае

Comment: Извините, не сразу  заметил знаки вопросов, поэтому не сразу понял о чем речь (объявление самой коллеции вы забыли привести в  вопросе).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [...] or when you use the TABLE collection expression to refer to a scalar nested table type, the database returns a virtual table with a single column.
> This name of this pseudocolumn is `COLUMN_VALUE`.

У колллекций скалярных типов всегда один [псевдостолбец](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COLUMN_VALUE-Pseudocolumn.html#GUID-66AD602D-7207-4BDF-9CB0-E7418CCC81D3), его имя - `COLUMN_VALUE`.

```
create or replace type t_numbers is table of number
/
declare
    a t_numbers;
    c t_numbers;
begin
    select * bulk collect into a from (
        select 1 d from dual union all 
        select 2 d from dual);
  
    select * bulk collect into c 
    from table(a) a1 
    where a1.column_value = 2;
  
    for i in 1..c.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line ('value('||i||')='||c(i));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

> value(1)=2

Comment: Спасибо! В гугле как-то неудачно загуглил, до этого сталкивался только с коллекциями записей.